# How to reduce system of first-order differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

I've been trying to reduce and/or eliminate the exponential terms in this system of differential equations to solve for x/y (both functions of t), but I am having trouble finding the relation between x and y:

---

$$
(ih)(dx/dt)=-u(B0)x-u(B1)e^{-2iwt}y\\
(ih)(dy/dt)=-u(B1)e^{2iwt}x+u(B0)y
$$
I think there is some relation I can make between x and y to make this easier to manage, but I haven't been able to find it yet.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Are $u , B0 , B1$ constants?

Comment: Yes, u, b0, and b1 are constants

Answer (score 1):

Copy of your equations :
$$
(ih)(dx/dt)=-u(B0)x-u(B1)e^{-2iwt}y\\
(ih)(dy/dt)=-u(B1)e^{2iwt}x+u(B0)y
$$
$h,b_0,b_1,w$ are given constants. $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are unknown functions that you are looking for.

HINT :

Let $a=\frac{b_0u}{ih}$ which is a given constant.

Let $b=\frac{b_1u}{ih}$ which is a given constant.
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-ax-be^{-2iwt}y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-be^{2iwt}x+ay$$

Change of functions :
$$x(t)=e^{-iwt}X(t)\quad\implies\quad \frac{dx}{dt}=e^{-iwt}(-iwX+\frac{dX}{dt})$$
$$y(t)=e^{iwt}Y(t)\quad\implies\quad \frac{dy}{dt}=e^{iwt}(iwY+\frac{dY}{dt})$$

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-ae^{-iwt}X-be^{-2iwt}e^{iwt}Y=e^{-iwt}(-iwX+\frac{dX}{dt})$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=-be^{2iwt}e^{-iwt}X+ae^{iwt}Y=e^{iwt}(iwY+\frac{dY}{dt})$

After simplification :

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dX}{dt}=(-a+iw)X-bY\\
\frac{dY}{dt}=(a-iw)Y-bX
\end{cases}$$
This is a classical system of two first order linear ODEs. I suppose that yo can take it from here.

Comment: The solutions I got from Mathematica X and Y are a giant nightmare, and I can't find the classical answers for an ODE in this form! Some help to finish would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @mavericks.physics. Thanks you very much for correcting the typo in the last system of equations.

Comment: @mavericks.physics. Why do you need Mathematica for solving so simple ODEs ? With $c=a-iw$ $$\begin{cases}X'=-cX-bY\\Y'=cY-bX\end{cases}\quad\begin{cases}Y=-\frac{1}{b}X'-\frac{c}{b}X\\X=-\frac{1}{b}Y'+\frac{c}{b}Y\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}-c(-\frac{1}{b}Y'+\frac{c}{b}Y)-bY=-\frac{1}{b}Y''+\frac{c}{b}Y'\\c(-\frac{1}{b}X'-\frac{c}{b}X)-bX=-\frac{1}{b}X''-\frac{c}{b}X'\end{cases}$$
Simplify and solve the two second order linear ODEs. If you can't, edit what you have done and show where you are stuck.